# Does Azure Blob Storage Container have Files amount limit?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As question mentioned,

does each container in Azure Storage Account has files amount limit to store?

Or we can store unlimited amount of files inside each container as long as there still have Free space under storage account?

Any official document can reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store unlimited amount of files inside each container as long as there still have free space under storage account, there is just a limit in the storage account and each blob.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#storage-limits

[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks!! This make me easier to understand it.